# 2d graphic - how to make a metronome clock hand

Tags: android, animation, graphics, drawing, 2d

I'm new to android. I have a metronom application and I want to put a graphic illustrating ticking cycle. (just a line that is fasten at one end and it's angle is changing) something like this: http://dir.coolclips.com/Entertainment/Music/Professional_Audio_Equipment/Metronomes/metronome_CoolClips_vc005895.jpg . Anybody knows how to make this?

Comment: Question is too vague, please specify what exactly do you want to ask for..

Comment: I want to make a some kind of swinging pendulum , but i dont know even how to start...

Comment: So you're asking how to compute the point of pendulum in 2D space..?

Comment: Yes I do. Ofc I'm not asking for someone to write me a complete code. I just need some hints where to start with it, and what methods i should use to make a line swing like a pendulum with given tempo value.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you are looking for is based on metronom (pendulum) frequency.

[image: pendulum equation]

Where [image: phi] is `current angle`, [image: phizero] is `initial angle`, [image: g] is `gravitational acceleration ~ 9.81 m/s`, [image: l] is `length of pendulum in m`, [image: t] is `time of simulation in sec`..